# How do I supply a professional license to a Docker image?

Tags: docker, containers, windows

I’m using `Windows Server Core` as part of an image I’m working on. When it's deployed to production, how do I supply a license to it?

Besides that, is this license needed to be bought for each image it's mounted on?

I've already mounted an image without an issue, so is simply having the license enough to avoid trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per an [archived Docker blog post](https://m-square.com.au/docker-for-windows-server-and-image2docker/) about Windows containers, it mentions the following:

> For production, licensing is at the host level, i.e. each machine or
> VM which is running Docker. Your Windows license on the host allows
> you to run any number of Windows Docker containers on that host. With
> Windows Server 2016 you get the commercially supported version of
> Docker included in the license costs, with support from Microsoft and
> Docker, Inc.

This is supported by the fact that [Microsoft and Docker are documented partners](https://www.docker.com/partners/microsoft/), which is in turn supported by Microsoft team member [Myles Keating](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/myles%20keating/?ws=usercard-mini) in a [separate thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1883e69a-1a58-44e9-a2f8-de89b01f8300/understanding-of-license-for-using-docker-on-windows-server-2016) on a similar topic who appears to have [joined Microsoft shortly after an internship](https://www.slate.com/blogs/business_insider/2015/04/02/stanford_graduates_get_fought_over_by_tech_companies_like_snapchat_and_have.html). The archived post is also mentioned in a [similar thread in the Docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/microsoft-windowsservercore-license/25983).

As a more general tip, to decide if [`Windows Server Core`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore) is really the image you'd like to use, check out the other available [Microsoft container images](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images).